# Why do I get an undefined method error in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Thanks for any help you can offer. I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the undefined method error described below. I'm new to Ruby on Rails, but I thought that by creating the @waypoint, I could call methods for it (like @waypoint.waypointaddress). My models use a belongs_to and has many (Newsavedmaps can have many waypoints.) I appreciate your feedback on what I'm doing wrong.

**Error Refers to if !@waypoint.waypointaddress.nil?**

```
    NoMethodError (undefined method `waypointaddress' for #<Array:NUMBERSHERE>):
    app/controllers/maptry_controller.rb:33:in `index'
```

**maptry controller**

```
    @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})
    @waypoint = Waypoint.find(:all, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})
    @newsavedmap.id = params[:newsavedmap_id]
    @newsavedmap.name = Newsavedmap.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).name
    @newsavedmap.optimize = Newsavedmap.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).optimize

    if !@newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id.nil?       
    @start_i_name = Masterlocation.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => @newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id}).i_name
    end
    if !@waypoint.waypointaddress.nil?  
    @waypoint_i_name = Masterlocation.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => @waypoint.waypoint_masterlocation_id}).i_name
    end
    if !@newsavedmap.end_masterlocation_id.nil?     
    @end_i_name = Masterlocation.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => @newsavedmap.end_masterlocation_id}).i_name
    end

    else
        @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new  
    end
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is my updated controller using code from Mu's comment. However, I'm getting an error of "undefined method `each'" for the maptry.html.erb view included below.

To clarify, there may be one or more waypoints that match the conditions. I'd like to return all of them and then do a `for each` in my maptry view.

Also, the `.where(...)` threw an undefined method error for `where`, so I used `find`. Maybe that's related to the problem? I'm in Rails 2.X.

**Code from maptry.html.erb**

```
    <% if params[:newsavedmap_id] %>
            <% for waypoint in @waypoint %>
          <option selected value="<%= @waypoint.waypointaddress %>"><%= @waypoint_inst_name %></option>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

**updated maptry controller**

```
    if params[:newsavedmap_id]
    @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})
    @waypoint = Waypoint.find(:first, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})
    @waypoint.waypointaddress = Waypoint.find(:first, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).waypointaddress
    @waypoint.waypoint_masterlocation_id = Waypoint.find(:first, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).waypoint_masterlocation_id
    @waypoint_inst_name = Masterlocation.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => @waypoint.waypoint_masterlocation_id}).inst_name
    @newsavedmap.id = params[:newsavedmap_id]
    @newsavedmap.name = Newsavedmap.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).name
    @newsavedmap.optimize = Newsavedmap.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newsavedmap_id]}).optimize

    if !@newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id.nil?       
    @start_inst_name = Masterlocation.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => @newsavedmap.start_masterlocation_id}).inst_name
    end
    if !@newsavedmap.end_masterlocation_id.nil?     
    @end_inst_name = Masterlocation.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => @newsavedmap.end_masterlocation_id}).inst_name
    end

    else
    @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.new  
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking ActiveRecord to find *all* the waypoints that match your conditions:

```
@waypoint = Waypoint.find(:all, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})
#-------------------------^^^^
```

That means that you'll get an Array in `@waypoint` and an Array (usually) won't have a `waypointaddress` method. Perhaps you meant to ask for the *first* one:

```
@waypoint = Waypoint.find(:first, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})
```

or better:

```
@waypoint = Waypoint.where(:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]).first
```

In general, you shouldn't be using `find` like that anymore; if you find yourself entering some `:conditions` in a `find` call, you should be saying `.where(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Mu! See my latest edit. FYI, looks like there's an extra bracket in the `where` statement you gave.

Comment: Yes, there was a stray `}` in there. You didn't mention that you were using Rails2 before so you're stuck with the `.find(:all ...)` and `.find(:first ...)` stuff. Looks like you want `@waypoint` to be a single instance in one place but an array in another. Should it be one waypoint or an array of waypoints (you might want to name the instance variable appropriately too).

Comment: Thanks, Mu. My updated code works. I did `@waypoint = Waypoint.find(:all, :conditions => {:newsavedmap_id => params[:newsavedmap_id]})` in the Maptry controller, and I got rid of the other waypoint references, like `@waypoint.waypointaddress`. In the maptry.html.erb, I changed `@waypoint.waypointaddress` for `waypoint.waypointaddress` and `@waypoint_inst_name` for `waypoint.waypoint_inst_name`.